# Generic Types, compiler and dynamic languages

Tags: language-design, typing, dynamic-typing, static-typing

In a public tender was the following statement:

"The use of generic types in object-oriented programming helps type checking at compile time."

it's true or false?
I believe it is false because the type checking compiler does not improve and this not have relation with object-oriented but in the type of language (weak-typing or strong-typing).
Someone please help me explain why this statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is true.  With generic types you specify a type when you instantiate the object and its use may be checked at compile time.  Without a type parameter on a class there is no way to check.

Comment: but in dynamic languages, not exists compiler but interpreter and the same advantages in use of generic type is mantained? And the verification of generic type help/assist the compiler?? for me, the advantages are in a semantic level, advantages in programming and reuse, but not in the compiler. what you think about this?

Comment: In dynamic, interpreted languages like Ruby the equivalent check is done at greater cost at runtime.  You can write methods which work for many different types and it is decided at runtime which one to call.